# How to find a correct :host selector for CSS only?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, selector

I can't find the correct :host selector for my Ionic4 + Angular8 project.
I have to get rid off padding property. In Ionic Framework there is special property  " --padding-top ". I need to change a value for the class="toolbar-container" from 3px to 0. Thank you in advance.
Here is the my

**HTML:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    #shadow-root (open)
    <div class="toolbar-background"></div>
    <div class="toolbar-container"></div> <!-- I need to get this class + :host-->
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**CSS:**

```
  :host {
        --padding-top: 3px;
        --padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
```

Here are my attempts:
1. I placed it in the root of a SCSS file.

```
    :host(.toolbar-container) {
     --padding-top:0;
     --padding-bottom:0
     padding:0 // just to check
    }
```

2. With inheritance:

```
ion-header {
    ion-toolbar{
     :host(.toolbar-container) {
     --padding-top:0;
     --padding-bottom:0
     padding:0
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: can you detail a bit what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you need  to change the property in `toolbar-container` class right?

Comment: Plochie, yep. You right. I edited my question.

Comment: Does this help?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()

Comment: No, it didn't help. As you see from my examples.